# MATLAB Structure array blackjack

Tags: matlab, structure

I'm writing a program to play blackjack and one of the functions calculates the score. It takes in an input which is a structure array of cards and one of the attributes is value (for an ace the value is 11). My function is supposed to determine if the total of the values is over 21 and if 1 of the cards is an ace, then the ace's value is changed to 1. Can anyone help me figure this out please?

```
for index=1:length(input)
    if(input(input).value == 11)
        input(index).value = 1;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `input(input)` in the `if` criteria should be `input(index)`. Compute the sum in the same `for` loop by accumulating each value as you loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually summing the cards in your original snippet. You also seem to have a typo in `input(input)`, I think this should be `input(index)`. If you wanted to do it with a for loop like you have, you'd do something like this:

```
total = 0;

for index=1:length(input)
    if(input(index).value == 11)
        input(index).value = 1;
    end;

    total = total + input(index);
end;
```

The more MATLAB way of doing things would be to avoid loops by using the `sum` in-built command.